# Comparing variable to grep statement

Tags: bash

I am trying to make the statement pass as true, if and only if the user input through stdin is within the guidelines of

```
[a-z_][a-z0-9_-]*
```

so if the user were to input a % or $ in their argument passed then it would return false. How could i go about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This reads from stdin and reports on true or false status (and exits if it is false):

```
grep -q '^[a-z_][a-z0-9_-]*$' && echo true || { echo false; exit 1 ; }
```

If `grep` finds a match to your regex, it sets its exit code to true (0) in which case the "and" (`&&`) clause is executed and "true" is returned.  If `grep` fails to find a match, the "or" (`||`) clause is executed and "false" is returned.  The `-q` flag to `grep` tells `grep` to be quiet.

If one were to use this in a script, one would probably want to capture the user input into a shell variable and then test it.  That might look like:

```
read -p "Enter a name: " var
echo "$var" | grep -q '^[a-z_][a-z0-9_-]*$' && echo true || { echo false; exit 1 ; }
```

To make it easy to add more statements to execute if the result is "true", we can write it out in a longer form with a place marked to add more statements:

```
read -p "Enter a name: " var
if echo "$var" | grep -q '^[a-z_][a-z0-9_-]*$'
then
    echo true
    # other statements to execute if true go here
else
   echo false
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Consider `grep -q` instead of redirecting to `/dev/null`. The `-q` flag is part of the [IEEE Std 1003.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html).

Comment: +1 hesitantly upvoting this. I'm still not sure if OP wants to print the string "false" or "true" or actually *return* a value.

Comment: If i type something that falls outside the parameters ex. test% it returns as true. I also need it to exit if its false

Comment: @user2860658 I added code to _also_ exit if false.  I copied the code back from the answer to my shell and I tried 'text%' and it returned false.  It is important to preceed the regex with `^` and follow it with `$` as these ensure that the whole input has to match the regex not just part.  If it continues to give you problems, let me have more details.

Comment: @John1024 that updated code does work, however when it comes back true i need for it to continue to run through 1 If statement. Right now i cant get it to execute the if statement after if it is true

Comment: @user2860658 I have added a variation to help with that.  Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what you mean by `return`. If by `return` you mean literal `false`, well, you have a small problem: UNIX scripts can *only* return an integer in the range 0-255. Normally in UNIX when a program *returns* it returns an exit status that indicates ([among other things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#POSIX)) the success or failure of the program. So you could just write:

```
grep -q ''^[a-z_][a-z0-9_-]*' || exit
```

At the top of your script. Since a shell script exits with the last value of `$?` anyway, that would only exit if the `grep` fails, and would exit with the same exit code as the `grep` statement itself. Technically this would mean returning `1`, but in UNIX that would be akin to `false`. If the `grep` succeeds, the script would continue, not returning anything until completion or another error condition occurs.

If what you really want is to print the string `"false"`, then see [John1024's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22599699/418413).